# How to Add Marker to Google Map on Mouseover Event

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

Can you please take a look at my try to this example : http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/dbw7n/10/
and let me know how I can add and remove marker to the map on mouseover event? I do not want to add any infowindows.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google Maps Api 3 Remove Selected Marker Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521766/google-maps-api-3-remove-selected-marker-only)

```
var id;
var markers = {};
var addMarker = function() {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        draggable: true
    });
    map.panTo(latlng);
    id = marker.__gm_id;
    markers[id] = marker;

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "rightclick", function(point) {
        id = this.__gm_id;
        delMarker(id);
    });
};

var delMarker = function(id) {
    marker = markers[id];
    marker.setMap(null);
};

$('#over_map').on('hover', function(e) {
    e.type == 'mouseenter' ? addMarker() : delMarker(id);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/dbw7n/14/