# show waypoint between two marker

Tags: html, google-maps, search

i want when add marker to map then show me waypoint when i droped second marker on the map here is my code for my custom marker, i tried google developers way but that did not worked for me. what should i do ?
i used this post custom marker : [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521766/google-maps-api-3-remove-selected-marker-only)

```html
<script>
      var map;
      function initAutocomplete() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 28.969820, lng: 50.842526},
          zoom: 15,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
        });var currentId = 0;
        </script>
```

Comment: There are no markers in your posted code, nor are there any way points

Answer (score 0):

here is my entire code:

```html
<script>
      var map;
      function initAutocomplete() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 28.969820, lng: 50.842526},
          zoom: 15,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
        });var currentId = 0;
          
       function initialize() {











// Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

        // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
        map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
          searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
        });

        var markers = [];
        // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
        // more details for that place.
        searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
          var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

          if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
          }

          // Clear out the old markers.
          markers.forEach(function(marker) {
            marker.setMap(null);
          });
          markers = [];

          // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          places.forEach(function(place) {
            if (!place.geometry) {
              console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
              return;
            }
            var icon = {
              url: place.icon,
              size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
            };

            // Create a marker for each place.
            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              icon: icon,
              title: place.name,
              position: place.geometry.location
            }));

            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
              // Only geocodes have viewport.
              bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
              bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }
          });
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });


var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
} 
          
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(28.969820, 50.842526),
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
};
          
map = new google.maps.Map($('#map')[0], myOptions);

/**
 * Global marker object that holds all markers.
 * @type {Object.<string, google.maps.LatLng>} 
 */
var markers = {};

/**
 * Concatenates given lat and lng with an underscore and returns it.
 * This id will be used as a key of marker to cache the marker in markers object.
 * @param {!number} lat Latitude.
 * @param {!number} lng Longitude.
 * @return {string} Concatenated marker id.
 */
var getMarkerUniqueId= function(lat, lng) {
    return lat + '_' + lng;
}

/**
 * Creates an instance of google.maps.LatLng by given lat and lng values and returns it.
 * This function can be useful for getting new coordinates quickly.
 * @param {!number} lat Latitude.
 * @param {!number} lng Longitude.
 * @return {google.maps.LatLng} An instance of google.maps.LatLng object
 */ 
var getLatLng = function(lat, lng) {
    return new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
};

/**
 * Binds click event to given map and invokes a callback that appends a new marker to clicked location.
 */ 
var addMarker = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
    var lat = e.latLng.lat(); // lat of clicked point
    var lng = e.latLng.lng(); // lng of clicked point
    var markerId = getMarkerUniqueId(lat, lng); // an that will be used to cache this marker in markers object.
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: getLatLng(lat, lng),
        map: map,
         animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        id: 'marker_' + markerId
    });
    markers[markerId] = marker; // cache marker in markers object
    bindMarkerEvents(marker); // bind right click event to marker
});

/**
 * Binds right click event to given marker and invokes a callback function that will remove the marker from map.
 * @param {!google.maps.Marker} marker A google.maps.Marker instance that the handler will binded.
 */ 
var bindMarkerEvents = function(marker) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "rightclick", function (point) {
        var markerId = getMarkerUniqueId(point.latLng.lat(), point.latLng.lng()); // get marker id by using clicked point's coordinate
        var marker = markers[markerId]; // find marker
        removeMarker(marker, markerId); // remove it
    });
};

/**
 * Removes given marker from map.
 * @param {!google.maps.Marker} marker A google.maps.Marker instance that will be removed.
 * @param {!string} markerId Id of marker.
 */ 
var removeMarker = function(marker, markerId) {
    marker.setMap(null); // set markers setMap to null to remove it from map
    delete markers[markerId]; // delete marker instance from markers object
};

         
      }
        
    </script>
```